# Sorting a list of numbers in increasing order

Tags: beginner, scheme, sorting

Here's a program I wrote to sort a list of numbers in increasing order (without using inbuilt sort function).

```
(define (sort-list l)
  (define first-element (if (not (null? l)) (car l) 0))
  (cond ((null? l) (quote ()))
        (else (cons (find-shortest l first-element) (sort-list (remove-member l (find-shortest l first-element)))))))

(define find-shortest
    (lambda (tl b)
      (cond ((null? tl) b)
            ((< (car tl) b) (set! b (car tl)) (find-shortest (cdr tl) b))
            (else (find-shortest (cdr tl) b)))))

(define remove-member
    (lambda (tl2 a)
      (cond ((null? tl2) (quote ()))
            ((= a (car tl2)) (cdr tl2))
            (else (cons (car tl2) (remove-member (cdr tl2) a))))))
```

It works, but I know it's very badly written. It has way too many recursions than what's necessary. Can someone suggest ways to make this code better?

Comment: I think that `find-shortest` should be named `find-smallest`.

Answer (score 6):

What you've written is called "selection sort", and it works fine. It's not the best sort, but it's not bad, either.  It's one of a class called "n^2" sorts, because it generally runs in time proportional to the square of the length of the list.

Selection sort is a somewhat painful sort to write in a recursive style, because removing an element from a list is not so natural.

You can make it look a smidgen more natural if you rebuild the list on the way back out after removing it. However, the second pass over the list (as you've written it) does *not* change the asymptotic running time; it's still "order n-squared".

One note: you gain nothing by mutating "b" in the body of "find-shortest." Instead, replace

```
(set! b (car tl)) (find-shortest (cdr tl) b)
```

with

```
(find-shortest (cdr tl) (car tl))
```

... to make your code shorter and cleaner.

Also, If you were in my class, I would ask you for purpose statements and test cases. :)

Comment: `O(n^2)` is pretty bad for sorting...

Comment: It's not bad for short collections, even though insertion sort would be better.

Answer (score 2):

- Within the `sort-list` function, you can just use `(car l)` in-place of `first-element` because your first `cond` clause ensures that in the remaining clauses, l is not null
- Also in `sort-list` You call `(find-shortest l first-element)` twice.  You could bind the result of this call once and save one call into `find-shortest`

Taking those two points and @Dan D.'s point about renaming `find-shortest` to `find-smallest` this is how my `sort-list` would look

```
(define (sort-list l)
  (cond ((null? l) '()) ; or (quote ()) - whichever you prefer
    (else (let ((smallest (find-smallest l (car l))))
            (cons smallest
                  (sort-list (remove-member l smallest)))))))
```